# Getting error while creating mdb file on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an app on vb.net. I am using visual studio community 2013. In some point I have to create mdb file. I searched all over internet and try every suggestions but always I get error on adox as follows (marked with '*')

Namespace ADOX
Class Catalog

```
Sub Create(sCreateString As String)
   ***Throw New NotImplementedException***
End Sub
```

End Class
End Namespace

my script quite long but this is what I use for create mdb file

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports ADOX
```

....

```
Public Sub MakeADataBase(ByVal sDBName As String)
        Dim catArch = New ADOX.Catalog
        catArch.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & sDBName & ";" & _
                "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
        catArch = Nothing
        MessageBox.Show("done")
End Sub
```

this code is working on new project, but not working on my original project and always generate above error. What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like exactly the same as on msdn: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317867. What are you passing through sDBName?

Comment: yes. I just copy and paste the code to try but it didn't work. for sDBName just a string containing path and file name. As i mention in the question. code is working on new project.